# Java Swing GUI Size under cross-platform

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cross-platform

I have a swing gui which has proper `JPanel` and `JDialog` size on windows platform with screen size from 13inch to 15inch. What I refer as proper size is that all the components in `JPanel` and messages at `JDialog` are properly shown.

However, when running under Ubuntu linux with Genome/Kde desktop, I find the not all components or messages are fully shown and it appears that either width or height is not enough and the GUI interface is cropped

Anybody has ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: You can check what operating system the program is currently running on and have it decide dimensions based on that if you'd like.

Comment: use proper LayoutManager correctly, use proper Font and Size, have to override Font or FontUIResource (in some case depends of) UIManager's Keys for all JComponents used in your GUI

Answer (score 3):

To have consistent UIs in multiple platforms you have to use LayoutManagers.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

There are several graphical editors that support creating swing user interfaces using LayoutMaganers. One example is WindowBuilder for Eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/

Answer (score 3):

Call [Window.pack()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) for your JDialog before showing it to make the window just big enough to fit all the components in it. This requires that you are using layout managers.